# Trying to change the drawable of Image view on clicking it in list adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, adapter

Actually the problem is when I click on image view of a single item its drawable is changing but many other random items have their image views changing as well with that click. Below is my code for the list adapter. I have seen the solution for this problem from some sources and I found that setting tags and then setting on click listeners works but it is not working for me. For reference, addMealItem is the id of the view which is to be changed when clicked. I have even added toast to test what is wrong but the toast is not very helpful in this situation.

```
class FoodsAdapter(application: Application, val context: Context, val clickListener: MealItemclickListener) : ListAdapter<MealItemModel, FoodsAdapter.ViewHolder>(MealItemDiffCallBack()) {
    val database = MealItemDatabase.getInstance(application)

    class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: MealitemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: MealItemModel, clickListener: MealItemclickListener, context: Context, database: MealItemDatabase) {
            binding.food = item
            GlobalScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    if(database.mealItemDao.getBreakfastItem(item.itemTitle)!=null) {
                        if (database.mealItemDao.getBreakfastItem(item.itemTitle).likedOrNot) {
                            binding.addmealItem.setTag("unliked")
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Unliked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                            binding.addmealItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_button)
                        } else {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                                Toast.makeText(context,"Liked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                            binding.addmealItem.setTag("liked")
                            binding.addmealItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_button_filled)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            binding.addmealItem.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener.onClick(item)
                GlobalScope.launch {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        if(database.mealItemDao.getBreakfastItem(item.itemTitle)!=null) {
                            if (database.mealItemDao.getBreakfastItem(item.itemTitle).likedOrNot) {
                                binding.addmealItem.setTag("unliked")
                                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                                    Toast.makeText(context,"Unliked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }
                                binding.addmealItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_button)
                                database.mealItemDao.getBreakfastItem(item.itemTitle).likedOrNot = false
                            } else {
                                binding.addmealItem.setTag("liked")
                                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                                    Toast.makeText(context,"Liked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                }
                                binding.addmealItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_button_filled)
                                database.mealItemDao.getBreakfastItem(item.itemTitle).likedOrNot = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

//            binding.addmealItem.setOnClickListener {
//                clickListener.onClick(item)
//                if (binding.addmealItem.drawable.constantState!!.equals(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_add_button, null)!!.constantState)) {
//                    binding.addmealItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_button_filled)
//                } else {
//                    binding.addmealItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_button)
//                }
//            }
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = MealitemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item, clickListener, context, database)
    }
}

class MealItemDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MealItemModel>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: MealItemModel, newItem: MealItemModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: MealItemModel, newItem: MealItemModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem.itemTitle == newItem.itemTitle
    }
}

class MealItemclickListener(val clickListener: (foodTitle: String) -> Unit) {
//    var flag = false
    fun onClick(mealItem: MealItemModel) {
//        flag = !flag
        return clickListener(mealItem.itemTitle)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is something of a like/unlike functionality.
You should try creating a custom drawable.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@android:color/liked"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/unliked"/>
</selector>
```

Using this as the drawable for the image in the xml, you will be able to access and switch between the 2 states of the image by accessing the view

```
addMealItem.isEnabled=true //(or false) this should be able to do the switching easily.
```

Comment: Will it only change the image view of a particular item in the adapter only or it will change image view of random items as adapter recycles its views?

Comment: The item you attached the above mentioned drawable to, you need to call the isEnabled setter on that item, so only that one will change.

Comment: No, I guess you got the question wrong. addMealItem is just an id for the image view of the layout and by item I mean the whole item(layout) of the adapter which the recycler view will show. So, the addMealItem(id of the image view) of random items in the adapter might change because it just recycles view holders which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change drawable color dynamically then use this i.e

```
(itemBinding.tvGrade.background as GradientDrawable).setColor(Color.parseColor(item?.gradeColor))
```

if you want to change drawable programmatically then do like this

```
binding.workBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.work_selected_bg)
```

Comment: It was not helpful.